# Java C double the value of the every even position of the value and sum up issue

Tags: java

I want to ask about what mistake I had make because i want to sum up the value in the odd position into Sumlast variable and the sum of even position value into Sumlastwo variable.

However I am required to double up the every value in even position then separate them into 2 digit like 9X2 = 18 ---> 1+8

For the odd value have no issue but when it reach the even position there is some issue.

Example I had did the input : 81
Output:
7
1

But when I type more digit like :9181
it become output:
27
2
it suppose to be (9X2) , (8X2) --> 18 , 16 = 1+8+1+6 = 16
output:
16
2

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
         int c = 1;
         int Sumlast = 0;
         int Sumlasttwo = 0;
         int numeven = 0;
           Scanner myscanner = new Scanner(System.in);
           System.out.print("Please enter your 8 digit number credit card: ");
           String num = myscanner.nextLine();
          if(num.length() != 8) //check the number of digit is 8 
          {
              int test = Integer.parseInt(num);
              while(test != 0)
              {
                  if(c%2 == 0) //even
                  {
                      numeven = test * 2;
                      while(numeven > 0)
                      {
                          Sumlasttwo += (numeven%10);
                          numeven /= 10;
                      }
                  }
                  else //odd
                  {
                      Sumlast += test%10;
                  }
                  test /= 10;
                  c++;
              }
              System.out.println(Sumlasttwo);
              System.out.println(Sumlast);

    }   
}
```

Comment: Kindly ignore the != 8 first because i want to do the inside function first...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to take the *digit* from `test` in the even-case.

```
          int test = Integer.parseInt(num);
          while (test != 0)
          {
              int digit = test % 10;
              if (c % 2 == 0) //even
              {
                  int numeven = digit * 2;
                  while (numeven > 0)
                  {
                      Sumlasttwo += numeven % 10;
                      numeven /= 10;
                  }
              }
              else //odd
              {
                  Sumlast += digit;
              }
              test /= 10;
              c++;
          }
```

Also it is more readable to declare `numeven` as near to its usage as possible.
`Sumlast` in java conventionally is written `sumLast`. Also `} else {` and `...) {` is such a convention, but for instance not in C, and not as holy as camel-case names.

---

Debugging would have helped.

Using a help method would have made the code better:

```
          boolean even = true;
          while (test != 0) {
              int digit = test % 10;
              if (even) {
                  sumEven += digitsSum(digit * 2);
              } else {
                  sumOdd += digit;
              }
              test /= 10;
              even = !even;
          }

private static void digitSum(int n) {
    int sum = 0;
    while (n > 0) {
        sum += n % 10;
        n /= 10;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Thanks , i had modified some by referring to yours and it solved my problem :D